# Having trouble extracting data from a web page with Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

This is supposed to connect to the web page, locate the HTML element by XPath, and then memorize the value of the text into a variable.

It connects to the page but it just just gives me the following result:

[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (5b3a1f161e663e550263860f3185a648)] -> xpath: //*[@id="tab-crew"]/div[1]/p/a]

```
public String reziser(String x) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ilija Sekaric\\Desktop\\Letterboxd\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    driver.navigate().to(x);
    String element="//*[@id=\"tab-crew\"]/div[1]/p/a";
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(element)));
    WebElement m=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tab-crew\"]/div[1]/p/a"));
    String result = String.valueOf(m);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Azy_Crw4282 How do I extract text from it then? For example, the xpath leads to this: " <a href="/director/wes-anderson/" class="text-slug">Wes Anderson</a> ", and I need to pull out Wes Anderson from it. Sorry for bothering you

Comment: see answer. You should also be able to locate elements by class.

Comment: @Azy_Crw4282 the tricky bit is that i just need the directors name, yet all of the crew elements are of the same class.

Comment: valueOf() method converts different types of values into string. Try with getText().

Comment: Just assign the directors a unique id :)

Comment: @MrCas Brilliant mate, worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Mr Cas, valueOf() method converts different types of values into string. Try with getText().